# CSS Animation Gets "Stuck" During Asynchronous Requests

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, css-animations

This only happens in IE. If I make a backend call animation stops until response is received. Animation is quite simple it just has rotate

``@keyframes loading
   100%
     transform: rotate(360deg)```

Comment: Can you please add html and css code or duplicate the issue using snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Please add [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)